Can we just simplify the numerator and denominator if denominator can equal zero?
Probably an extremely stupid question, but I somehow haven't found an answer to it. So if I am graphing a function like $$\tan(x)\cot(x)$$ I can obviously write it as $$\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\cdot\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}=1$$
Now if we follow the same logic as $$x^{\log_{x}{1}}=1; \space x>0$$
Then our trig function's domain should be $$R\setminus\{\frac{\pi}{2}n|n\in{Z}\}$$
Is this correct? I usually check my graphing through desmos and it does exclude the point x=0 but not the other ones.

Yes, that is correct.

Any plotting program uses a finite number of points, all at some rational numbers. Therefore the only solution for $\sin x=0$ or $\cos x=0$ is $x=0$.
